# Count cells if they have date information

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to get a count of my cells that have date information.

The format is: ['2020-12-19T00:00:00.939Z', '2020-12-19T00:45:20.499Z']

However, the rest of the cells in that column have [] - not blank, so I can't just do a COUNTIF(A1:A100,"*"). I would like to know how I can format this COUNTIF statement to grab only the cells with date and time data, because also this date could range from any day in the last year. I am using Google Sheets, the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
=sum(Arrayformula(if(Substitute(A1:A12,"[]","")="",0,1)))
```

[image]

- Substitute cells without date "[]" with empty cell ""
- Check if cells are empty set to 0 or 1
- use arrayformula() to apply formula to all cell rows
- get the sum of the arrayformula() which will give you the count of non-empty cells in your range

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the "short" nature of the cells you don't want counted:

```
sumproduct(--len(A1:A100)>2)
```

This assumes that you have either have date data or cells like `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(COUNTA(IFNA(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A100; "[]"; ))))
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it but it gave an answer of 1 instead of the count of cells with the dates

Comment: Thank you for updating! I tried that one and it gave a count of the selected cells (A1:A100), but didn't exclude the [] cells unfortunately